# Minifigures creator?

Tags: minifigures

Does a website to create custom minifigs exist?

For exemple, you choose your head (between all official LEGO releases), torso, legs, and hair, and then you can purchase it for the same price as you would if you were buying each of the pieces from a Bricklink seller.

I'm looking for a simple way to create yourself and your friend's avatars in LEGO.

Answer (score 6):

[Minifig Generator](http://www.baseplate.com/toys/minifig/) might work for you.

Or maybe the <del>[SigFig Creator](http://sigfigcreator.thelegomovie.com/).</del>

Flash based, but also fun: [Mini-Mizer](http://www.reasonablyclever.com/mm2/mini2.swf).

Even better, suggested by rioforce: [LEGO Universe Minifig Wizard](http://legouniversenews.forummotion.com/h2-lun-minifig-wizard)

I'm sure there are more...

6 hours later...  OH!  you mean like an actual bit of molded plastic.

For that, probably your best bet is using one of the above to find some approximation and then hit up something like Bricklink to buy the proper parts.

Comment: The last one seems to be the best one.

Comment: If you're going to list fan-made digital minifig creators, you may as well mention the LUN Minifig Wizard: http://legouniversenews.forummotion.com/h2-lun-minifig-wizard

The Mini-Mizer uses a ton of custom parts, so if you're looking to design a minifig that you might want to buy, it's not best for you.

Comment: It looks like the SigFig Creator is down.  I was really hoping for something that was complete like bricklink, but had a nice interface like https://minifigs.me/ .  Thanks for showing some options that google has buried.

Answer (score 4):

If you are close to an official LEGO store they have stations to make your own minifigures. LEGO also has an online Pick-A-Brick store where you can buy parts individually. They have a decent selection of legs, heads and headgear, but the toros selection is quite limited. You can check it out here: http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-11998. Other that that, BrickLink is your best option. Just make sure you create a Wanted List, so you can minimize the number of sellers you need to shop from.

Comment: Yeah, but it's hard to see pieces. Thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean hard to see pieces? If you explain your question better I could probably help.